# nsuserdefaults synchronize method slows down the application

Tags: iphone, performance, nsuserdefaults

I am doing a calculation intensive operation in loops(hundreds for iterative formulas).In each loop the values are fetched from nsuserdefaults directly and calculated and saved back.my question is that should i use -synchronize method each time i write into nsuserdefaults?.i think without using this method. my application runs much faster. Does using synchronize slows down the calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does using synchronize slows down the calculations?

Yes, absolutely.  `synchronize` writes the current user default values to the disk.

> should i use -synchronize method each time i write into nsuserdefaults?.

No absolutely not.  If you have a long loop, where you are changing user defaults, the values are saved in memory.  It won't mess up your calculations.  It is only necessary to save to disk after the loop is done.

`synchronize` is usually done:

1. manually, before the app is terminated or sent to background
2. automatically by the system every few minutes
3. manually by the program after some important changes are made that you don't want to risk losing in the event of a crash or sudden power off.

In your case, after the long loop, you want to do it for reason 3.

By doing it every time within the loop, you are just unnecessarily writing values to flash, which you likely immediately overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

No! You should not. Consider to `synchronize` in `applicationWillTerminate`.

Comment: my question is that suppose in my first loop a value is calculated. based on this value the next loop calculation works,now if the system has not called synchronise method within a loops time.will the calculations get wrong......what is the use if i am calling synchronize in appwill terminate????

Comment: `synchronize` stands for _write to disk_. You may use shared instance of `NSUserDefaults` (and values in there) in your program. Consider it to be just a dictionary. At the end of the program you write those values to disk.

Comment: @debleek63: you should add that comment to your answer, it is good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

No. In theory you never need to call it at all, it will be done for you (it “is automatically invoked at periodic intervals”). In practice, it's a good idea to do so in `applicationWillResignActive:`.

Comment: but if the loops time is lesser than the update intervals will my calculations go wrong?

Comment: No, `synchronize` just updates the "disk" with what you've been saving in memory.